# Accessing javascript window variable in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

in my Puppeteer script I'm using a file JS to be executed before loading the page:

```js
const preloadFile = fs.readFileSync('./file.js', 'utf8');
const id = await page.evaluateOnNewDocument(preloadFile);
```

the file.js contains :

```js
const i = setInterval(()=>{
  if (window.turnstile) {
    clearInterval(i)
    window.turnstile.render = (a,b) => {
        b.userAgent = navigator.userAgent
    window.tsCallback = b.callback
    window.action = b.action
    window.data = b.cData
      console.log(b)
      return 'foo'
    }
  }
},50)
```

This script print on the browser console an object (action, Cdata, callback...)

I want from pupetter side to get this object and be able to make a call to the function callback().

I have used the page.evaluate(), but doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use my Puppeteer wrapper lib https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/pulls to achieve this goal (getting object from browser console), using `new ConsoleDriver(context).getMessages()` method and then convert received object from array into JSON...

or just copy ConsoleDriver code to your project.

[Reference](https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/src/console/consoleDriver.ts#L104C1-L104C1)

[Example of usage](https://github.com/wix-incubator/bubanai/blob/main/tests/console/consoleDriver.spec.ts)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but to retrieve the console msg I had already done this :
page.on('console', async msg => {
  const args = await Promise.all(msg.args().map(arg => arg.executionContext().evaluate(arg => {
    if (arg instanceof Error)
      return arg.message;
    return arg;
  }, arg)));
  console.log(...args);
});
and I can getall the args, but how can I call the method window.tsCallback ('TOKEN') ?

Comment: Did you try to debug and see what is tsCallback?? For example, `await page.evaluate('console.log(5); window.tsCallback = () => console.log(6); window.tsCallback();');`
 prints 5 6 in browser. Are you sure that tsCallback is callable?

Comment: in fact the js code print an object (data, and callback function) from the browser console I can type callback('TOKEN'à and it passes and the I bypass the captcha, but as I said I need to do this from puppetter side

Comment: and for your page.evaluate(), it print 5 and 6 on browser console

Comment: @martin so, if I understood you correct, you need callback function from browser in Puppeteer instance. 
Page evaluate can return only serializable objects. Functions are not serializable. So, to execute callback in Puppeteer context you need to do smth like this:

`const tokenFunc = await paga.evaluate(() => {
        window['callback'] = () => true;
        return window['callback'].toString();
      });
      const res = new Function('return ' + tokenFunc)();
      console.log(res()); //returns true`

Comment: I'm not sure what does this function and how I can used to call the callback function inside the window variable